# How to disable SSRS 2008 manager

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Can you disable the SSRS 2008 manager (http://mydomain/reports), while leaving the report server working (http://mydomain/reportserver)?

**EDIT**: Got it! This is how you do it in SSRS: 
[Turn off Report Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677363.aspx#ReportManager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677363.aspx#ReportManager

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use the config tool and just don't opt to enable the Reports Virtual Directory.

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1453

Comment: I'm using SSRS 2008 and the config tool is different: http://i.imgur.com/kShZb.jpg.

Comment: Ok. So it would be this tool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156305.aspx.